# Write PDF in Zend Controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, pdf-generation, zend-db, zend-db-table

I require make mediantes reports query the database, so my idea is to write "text" in a PDF with the model view controller know how to perform queries and this is the code I use the controller to generate the PDF

```
public function mensualAction() {

    //Para cargar la librería:
    require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php';
    require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

    //Para crear un nuevo documento PDF:
    $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

    //Para crear una nueva página:
    $pdf->pages[] = ($page = $pdf->newPage('A4'));
    $pdf->pages[] = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);

    //Obtener ancho y alto de la página:
    $ancho = $page->getWidth();
    $alto = $page->getHeight();

    //Usar estilos:
    $estilo = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $estilo->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));
    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);
    $estilo->setFont($font, 10);
    $estilo->setStyle($style);

    //Escribir texto:
    $page->drawText("Hola Mundo", $x, $y);

    //Insertar imágenes:
    //$img = Zend_Pdf_ImageFactory::factory('sentidoweb.png');
    //$page->drawImage($img, $x, $y, $x+&ancho, $y+$alto);
    //Devolver la salida:
    echo $pdf->render();

    //Eso sí, antes hay que tener en cuenta que tenemos que devolver al inicio del script el Content-Type:

    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    // Si queremos que se devuelva como un fichero adjunto
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"prueba.pdf\"");
}
```

**Error in browser:**

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Pdf_Style::setStyle() in ../application/controllers/ReportesController.php on line 32
```

**Line 32:**

```
$estilo->setStyle($style);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two comments:
1 - `$style` is not defined.
2 - `setStyle()` is not a method of `Zend_Pdf_Style`.

However, `SetStyle()` is a method of `Zend_Pdf_Canvas_Abstract` and `Zend_Pdf_Page` extends `Zend_Pdf_Canvas_Abstract`. 

So maybe what you want to do is:

```
 $page->setStyle($estilo);
```

I hope it will help. :)